# What is the minimum pumping lemma length of $01^*0^*1$?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I've taken the following steps to prove that the minimum pumping length (PL) of the above language, $L= 01^*0^*1$:

1. Set a PL. I chose $p=2$
2. Choose a string from $L$ where $|w|\geq p$, I chose $w=011$. $|w|=3 \geq p=2$
3. Split the word, $w$ into constituent parts, $x,y,z$ such that the following are true:

- $y\neq\varepsilon$
- $|xy|\leq p$
- For any $k \geq0$, $xy^kz\in L$

4. So I chose:

- $x=0$, $y=1$, $z=1$
- $y=1\neq\varepsilon$
- $|xy|=2\leq p=2$
- $xy^kz=01^k1 \in L$

My lecturer however has said that the minimum pumping length is $3$, and I don't understand why, and cannot ask him. Am I right, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: You got the definition of *pumping length* wrong. It is the minimum $p$ for which the conclusion of the pumping lemma holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a language $L$, its *pumping length* is the minimum $p$ for which the following holds:

> Every word $w \in L$ of length at least $p$ can be decomposed as $w = xyz$ such that $|xy| \leq p$, $y \neq \epsilon$, and $xy^iz \in L$ for all $i$.

Showing that a *particular* word can be pumped isn't enough — you have to show that *all* words in the language of length at least $p$ can be pumped, and moreover in such a way that $|xy| \leq p$.

The pumping length cannot be $2$ since the word $01 \in L$ cannot be pumped down, that is, there is no decomposition $w = xyz$ with $y \neq \epsilon$ and $xy^0z \in L$.

Comment: Yep. Looking back on it, I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it: "Pumping length p" means that if you take a state machine, then any word w in the language with a length ≥ p must have re-entered the same state after at processing at most p characters of the input.

That's not true with p = 2; 01 is in the language but doesn't require re-entering the same state within the first two characters.